# The term for a Person who is asked to state a negative about themselves, but actually says a positive

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for the term of a person who is asked to state something negative about themselves but actually states something positive..

EX:

"I guess one of my biggest faults is that I care too much"

"I guess one of my biggest faults is that I am too much of a perfectionist"

Comment: A relatively recent internet slang term for such a remark is a _humblebrag_. But this doesn’t refer to the person, but to the remark itself. You might by extension call the person a _humblebragger_, and while it’s not an established term, it should be understood by anyone familiar with the term _humblebrag_.

Comment: A modern term that literally answers your question is ***interviewee***, but I'll see if I can come up with anything constructive.

Comment: Are you looking for a term for the *person*, or a term for the *statement*? It will help people to give you better answers if you include an example sentence showing how you want to use the term, with a ___ or other placeholder where you want the word to go. (This is also technically required for [single-word-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).)

Comment: I'd say that person was being [**disingenuous**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/disingenuous) - *slightly dishonest, or not speaking the complete truth.*

Comment: It's an example of **Positive Thinking**: we dare not say anything "negative", for fear of attracting *extremely harsh and judgmental criticism* from those in 'authority' -- so if we want a **job**, we choose our words very carefully.

Comment: A narcissist . . .

Comment: Relating back to @MattBecker82 ' s suggestion of a humplebragger. The following article uses the term in the way described (but in plural form): https://nypost.com/2018/01/15/humblebraggers-are-even-worse-than-full-on-braggers/

Answer (score 0):

Self-applauding might be close.